# Openshift node distribution

Tags: redhat, docker, openshift-online-3

I am relatively new to Openshift 3.4 container platform administration and basic architecture. We have an openshift platform with 3 masters and several nodes.These nodes will support different customer applications (different tenants).
Shall routers (openshift router for data traffic) be installed/running directly on application nodes (nodes where you have application/customer pods) or better be running on specific infrastructure node ?

same question with docker registry?

Answer (score 1):

Red Hat always recommends that or real environments it's always better to have dedicated infrastructure nodes because:

1. These machines which have critical won't be sharing resources with the application software
2. Better network control and isolation

Normally you use infra nodes for routers, metrics, log aggregation and registry. Sometimes the logging project is taken out to other kind of nodes that only run that due to the high requirements of ElasticSearch